# ExpressJS - custom file extension for view partials

Tags: node.js, partial-views, express

I am trying to include a view partial (inside the same folder) which has a `.js` extension this way:

`<%- partial('somePartial.js') %>`

And, I get this error: `Cannot find module 'js'`

The view engine is using the file extension to look for the module... Any idea if this possible? I want to keep the .js extension for syntax highlighting purposes (of course, I can just set-up my IDE to treat a file with extension `*.js.ejs` as a JS file, but I rather not do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use app.register() like this:

```
 app.register('.extension', require('ejs'));
```

this will use .extension for rendering.

Comment: Can I register multiple extensions?

Comment: In express version 3.X register is renamed to engine. app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);